# How to mock HttpContext.User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, httpcontext

I am working on a Asp.net MVC 5 project and I am trying to setup a mock to return a custom principal within a controller. I have search and tried different approach suggested but none of them works.

I have a BaseController which all my controllers inherit from. The BaseController has a User property which return HttpContext.User in the getter. The HttpContext.user returns a value when called within the project but return a null when call from a unit test project.

**BaseController**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected virtual new CustomPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as CustomPrincipal; }  ***<== Line with issue***
    }
}
```

**Custom Principal**

```
public class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal, ICustomPrincipal
{
    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool   IsStoreUser { get; set; }

    public CustomPrincipal(string username)
    {
        this.Identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class DocumentsController : BaseController
    {
        public ViewResult ViewDocuments()
        {
            var userType = User.IsStoreUser ? UserType.StoreUser : UserType.Corporate;  ***<== User is null when calling from a unit test.***
        }
    }
```

**Test Case**

```
[Test]
public void ViewDocuments_WhenCalled_ShouldReturnViewModel()
{
    // Arrange
    var principal = new CustomPrincipal("2038786");
    principal.UserId = "2038786";
    principal.FirstName = "Test";
    principal.LastName = "User";
    principal.IsStoreUser = true;

    var _mockController = new Mock<DocumentsController>(new UnitOfWork(_context)) { CallBase = true };
        _mockController.Setup(u => u.User).Returns(principal);  ***<== Error - "Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: u => u.User"***

    // Act
    var result = _controller.ViewDocuments();
}
```

I'm using nUnit and Moq to create the mock object but I not sure what I'm doing wrong. I need to mock the return of User.IsStore in the DocumentControl to return the value of IsStore in the custom principal object i created in the test.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make a mock http context

```
private class MockHttpContext : HttpContextBase {
    private readonly IPrincipal user;

    public MockHttpContext(IPrincipal principal) {
        this.user = principal;
    }

    public override IPrincipal User {
        get {
            return user;
        }
        set {
            base.User = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Arrange test accordingly.

```
[Test]
public void ViewDocuments_WhenCalled_ShouldReturnViewModel() {
    // Arrange
    var principal = new CustomPrincipal("2038786");
    principal.UserId = "2038786";
    principal.FirstName = "Test";
    principal.LastName = "User";
    principal.IsStoreUser = true;

    var mockUoW = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    //...setup UoW dependency if needed
    var controller = new DocumentsController(mockUoW.Object);
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext {
        Controller = controller,
        HttpContext = new MockHttpContext(principal)
    };

    // Act
    var result = controller.ViewDocuments();

    //Assert
    //...assertions
}
```

Don't mock system under test. Mock its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Nkosi, this works great. Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: @Nkosi Could you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647669/httpcontext-user-not-populated-in-net-core-app

Answer (score 6):

It gets a lot easier if you don't depend on `HttpContext` directly. Create an `IUserProvider` interface and an implementation that depends on `HttpContext` (e.g. `HttpContextUserProvider`), then stub the `IUserProvider` in your tests.

The `IUserProvider` should be passed along to your controller via dependency injection.

Comment: Stijn, thanks for your response to my question. Do you have an example of what you are suggesting. I am always interested in simplifying/refactoring my code where possible. Thanks.

Comment: @EdmandLooi I'll try to include an example later this week. In case I forget, feel free to ping me again in a week or so :)

Comment: From the Microsoft Documentation: how to add `HttpContext` via Dependency Injection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components